# Chimera not running on my Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, python

I installed chimera and upon trying to run it via terminal, it gives me the following error message:

```
/.local/chimera/bin$ ./chimera #This is the command that i used to launch it
#Below is the error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/chimera/share/__main__.py", line 73, in <module>
    value = chimeraInit.init(sys.argv)
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/chimera/share/chimeraInit.py", line 666, in init
    import chimera
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/chimera/share/chimera/__init__.py", line 2777, in <module>
    from SimpleSession import BEGIN_RESTORE_SESSION, END_RESTORE_SESSION
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/chimera/share/SimpleSession/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from save import saveSession, sessionID, noAutoRestore, autoRestorable, \
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/chimera/share/SimpleSession/save.py", line 13, in <module>
    from chimera import replyobj, selection, SessionPDBio, version
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/chimera/share/chimera/replyobj.py", line 24, in <module>
    import Tkinter
  File "/home/nicholas/.local/chimera/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1: undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var
```

What am I supposed to do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing tk-dev

```
sudo apt-get install tk-dev
```

After that, re-run make command and start chimera again